Is there a method for checking if an array has a certain element in it?
In this instance, I want to find out if a array has a element in it:
function OnTestCmd(scriptCmdData){
    print(["Jenny", "Matilda", "Greta"].indexOf("Matilda"))     //Error: Object doesn't support this property or method (0x800a01b6)
    print(["Jenny", "Matilda", "Greta"].includes("Matilda"))   //Error: Object doesn't support this property or method (0x800a01b6)
    
    arr = new Array("Jenny", "Matilda", "Greta")
    print(arr.indexOf("Greta"))                               //Error: Object doesn't support this property or method (0x800a01b6)
    }

I am told I can use includes() or indexOf() but neither seem to work
Looking at MS docs for Jscript, there does not seem be a includes() method but it does have indexOf() which just errors out.
Edit1: The print function is not complicated at all and I dont think its the issue, here it is, the DOpus.Output() method is documented here:
    function print(str){
        DOpus.Output(str)
    }


In which envronment are you running this? Maybe it's print triggering the error?

I literally copied the parts of the code in the question that are actually related to arrays into the console of the browser's developer tools and verified that they work. Therefore your problem is probably thatprint() does not do what you think it does. Try console.log()  if you want to display things.

There is no implicit method with name "print", use console.log and it would work fine

For clarification, what situation is forcing you to use JScript?

The environment must be really ancient, Array.prototype.indexOf was not a method in ECMAScript 3, it was added to version 5.

@Pointy I am writting a script for a windows programme called Directory Opus, it uses JScript, an example of a script for Opus. The print function is using the DOpus.Output() method to print to its console. I dont have the option to use JavaScript

@Teemu I am using Jscript, which I believe MS abandoned some time ago.

I updated my OP with more information about the print() function.

@Ralf_Reddings JScript is not an environment, it's a language. An environment is something running the script, like a browser, WSH, etc. Opus seems to be your environment here.

@Teemu, I see, understood. Will keep this in mind. Cheers

JScript doesn't have Array.indexOf, but it has String.indexOf, which is likely why there's confusion.
Could use a ponyfill to provide the necessary functionality without modifying Array, which is safest.
function arrayIndexOf (list, element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // Should do more to confirm equality.
    // Can't use === though.
    if (list[i] == element) {
      return i
    }
  }

  return -1
}


Thank you for the conclusive answer on the matter of indexOf() and for the solution!

@Ralf_Reddings No problem; it was interesting and fun :) The pony fill is not 100% feature-complete compared to the real Array.indexOf, but it would not be hard to add in the missing behavior (if it's needed for your implementation) based on the MDN definition.
